# Domain or IP exists check in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command, ping

I want to know if a given website or IP address is online or offline. I researched a lot, but all I can find is to install some software or using the ping command.

I did this test:

```sh
ping -c 5 -n example.com
```

It outputs the expected result, but when I do the following where a website does not ext, the result is almost the same as if website existed, with 0% packet loss. Please see the screenshot attached.

```sh
ping -c 5 -n examplesurenotexists.com
```

I am confused by this. Is there a better way to do this task?

[image: Output of ping]

Comment: If you add the `-q` option, you get a Quiet output, just a line that can be easier and faster to parse or understand.

Comment: @fedorqui, I know that. Problem is to find IP is "online or offline".

Comment: This is not possible, when a site is down it CANNOT reply to ICMP echo requests (unless something in the middle is intercepting such requests and spoofing replies). Moreover, please note that some machines are intentionally configured to ignore such requests, so this will only work on the machines you have replying to ping requests enabled.

Comment: @AdamSiemion, thanks. Just curious to know. If not possible then how peoples do this? there are also lots of services who check website stats.

Comment: @MadanSapkota in my previous comment what I wanted to say was that in most cases it works, it is just not 100% reliable method. If you want to check if an HTTP server works ask it for a page, Alfe's answer will tell you how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know if a *website* is online of offline, simply check the website:

```
if curl -s http://www.alfe.de >/dev/null
then
  echo "online"
else
  echo "offline"
fi
```

Using `ping` instead would not test the HTTP protocol (which is for websites) but the ICMP protocol; one is merely independent from the other (but of course, if the host is down, both won't work).  There are sites which still react on ICMP while the HTTP server is down (this is rather typical) and there are sites which won't react on ICMP although the HTTP server is up and running functioning perfectly well.